# not closed connection prevents connecting to database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, connection

I have an APS.Net MVC with SQL Server Backend hosted on IIS7. I have a problem connection not closed with the following exception message:

"There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be be closed first".

When I refresh the page, application continue to work with no problems. After sometime, the following exception appears, but not always:

ExcuteReader requires an open and available connection, the connection current state is open.

application stops working then, in the sense that I could access the log in page, but could not log in, sometimes it takes about 10 minutes to be able to log in, and sometimes it takes longer until restarting IIS.

my question: does the first exception message have a relation to the second message, preventing users from logging in to server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to your connection string
. See below an example:

```
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.0;Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=True;Multipleactiveresultsets=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please explain breafly how this will help in my case. how setting MultipleActiveResultSets=true will solve the problem

Comment: From the error message what you provided, it looks like you execute a query while iterating over the results from another query. 
One thing that can cause this is lazy loading triggered when iterating over the results of some query. If that is the problem,
it can be solved by allowing MARS in your connection string.

Comment: thanks again, another question plz, will the above second exception message have direct relation to what appeared in the first exception message, or it is another story

Comment: Without your code, it's hard to imagine where the problem is exactly, and also if the two problems are related. I guess just give it a try.

Comment: it is a big application with thousands lines of code. I will try and give feedback.